# Extract multiple objects from list in R

Tags: r, subset

I have some output from the `vegan` function `specaccum`. It is a list of 8 objects of varying lengths;

```
> str(SPECIES)
List of 8
$ call       : language specaccum(comm = PRETEND.DATA, method = "rarefaction")
$ method     : chr "rarefaction"
$ sites      : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
$ richness   : num [1:5] 20.9 34.5 42.8 47.4 50
$ sd         : num [1:5] 1.51 2.02 1.87 1.35 0
$ perm       : NULL
$ individuals: num [1:5] 25 50 75 100 125
$ freq       : num [1:50] 1 2 3 2 4 3 3 3 4 2 ...
- attr(*, "class")= chr "specaccum"
```

I want to extract three of the lists ('richness', 'sd' and 'individuals') and convert them to columns in a data frame. I have developed a workaround;

```
SPECIES.rich <- data.frame(SPECIES[["richness"]])
SPECIES.sd <- data.frame(SPECIES[["sd"]])
SPECIES.individuals <- data.frame(SPECIES[["individuals"]])
SPECIES.df <- cbind(SPECIES.rich, SPECIES.sd, SPECIES.individuals)
```

But this seems clumsy and protracted. I wonder if anyone could suggest a neater solution? (Should I be looking at something with lapply??) Thanks!

---

Example data to generate the `specaccum` output;

```
Set.Seed(100)
PRETEND.DATA <- matrix(sample(0:1, 250, replace = TRUE), 5, 50)
library(vegan)
SPECIES <- specaccum(PRETEND.DATA, method = "rarefaction")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can concatenate the names in a `vector` and extract it

```
 SPECIES.df <- data.frame(SPECIES[c("richness", "sd", "individuals")])
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! That looks much better. I had been experimenting with that sort of thing, but was messing up the '(' and the '['

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, similar to akrun, is: 
    ctoc1 = as.data.frame(cbind(SPECIES$richness, SPECIES$sd, SPECIES$individuals))

Please note that in both cases (my answer and akrun) you will get an error if the lengths of the columns do not match. 
e.g.: SPECIES.df <- data.frame(SPECIES[c( "sd", "freq")]) 
*Error in data.frame(richness = c(20.5549865665613, 33.5688503093388, 41.4708434700877,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows:7, 47*

If so, remember to use length() function : 
    length(SPECIES$sd) <- 47  # this will add NAs to increase the column length.
    
SPECIES.df <- data.frame(SPECIES[c("sd", "freq")])  
    SPECIES.df  # dataframe with 2 columns and 7 rows.

Comment: Hi @Ann, Thanks for your suggestions. I didn't know about the `length()` function, nice tip!